# XCode 15 Provisioning Profile without Developer account

Tags: provisioning-profile, apple-developer, xcode15

[edit - solved] I think my problem was a lag time after initializing the free developer account.

Attempting to target a physical device (iPhone 15) from XCode 15 / Swift. Trying to not purchase an Apple Developer account at this time. The device is visible as a target in XCode but the build fails when switched to device. I get as far as Signing & Capabilities - Automatically Manage Signing - which gives the error:

> Communication with Apple failed
> Your team has no devices from which to generate a provisioning profile. Connect a device to use or manually add device IDs in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.

Is this possible with XCode 15 - testing on a device without developer account? All the tutorials / examples I've found about provisioning without the account are 2+ years old and lead to a screen that is different.

Is there an XCode 15 issue with OSX 13.5.2? For software reasons I can't upgrade to 14 right now.

thanks in advance for any info

XCode 15.0.1
OSX 13.5.2

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets this far I think the problem was a wait time after initializing the free developer account. I've managed to load and test on the device without paying for the full account.